# Creation a always_use_https pagerule failed with error Invalid setting always_use_https

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-cloudflare

Here is my rule

```
resource "cloudflare_page_rule" "https-only" {
    zone = "${var.domain}"
    target = "http://*${var.domain}/*"
    priority = 1

    actions = {
        always_use_https = true,
    }
}
```

The documentation says the default value of `always_use_https` is **false**. I want to turn this rule on for all http traffic to the zone.

When I apply the rule, I get this error:

```
* cloudflare_page_rule.https-only: Failed to create page rule: error 
from makeRequest: HTTP status 400: content "
{\"success\":false,\"errors\":[{\"code\":1004,\"message\":\"Page Rule 
validation failed: See messages for details.\"}],\"messages\":
[{\"code\":1,\"message\":\".settings[0]: Invalid setting 
always_use_https\",\"type\":null}],\"result\":null}"
```

I have tried alternative value such as 'on', but it gets rejected because terraform says the setting only accept boolean value.

How can I set this rule with terraform?

Answer (score 1):

a had the same issue with some other zone override settings as well. what worked for me was to do a complete terraform destroy, upgrade to cf 2.2.0 provider and do an apply. looks like older versions of the provider might be out of sync with the apis to perform some of the zone override functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your domain to use Cloudflare's nameservers.